# How to Resize Window Split in VIM in Mac?

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted this question to be there just so it will also help someone in the future. Some of the VIM keyboard shortcuts have problems in the Mac keyboard convention. I read that **Ctrl + W + >** will resize.

But it doesn't seem to be working. What's the real way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to resize the VIM view, while in the Normal mode, type `:resize number`
For example, `:resize 10` will create a view with 10 lines.

If you want to resize a window that can be any window and not just VIM, have a look at this post: https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x

Comment: @SreejithRamakrishnan, `:help window-resize`

Answer (score 3):

You must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> first, then <kbd>></kbd>. Same for *every" `<Modifier-Key><Key>` mapping.

Comment: Ya. It's working! A bit tedious though. By the way, what's the markdown to get that gorgeous style you use for keyboard shortcuts? (the white key-like box)

Comment: The problem is, doing Ctrl + W and > moves it one step. Then I've to do it again for another step which is tedious.

Comment: That's `<kbd>Key</kbd>`. You can do `10<C-w>>`.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `w` then `>` works for width adjustment, for height use `Ctrl` + `w` then `+` (or `-`)